# Блокировка главного окна в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

На сцене главного окна есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую создается дополнительное окно следующим образом:

```
public static void create()
{
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
    //Здесь идет добавление элементов в pane
    stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
    stage.setWidth(500);
    stage.setHeight(600);
    stage.show();
}
```

Мне требуется сделать так, чтобы главное окно было заблокированным (т.е. пользователь не мог ничего нажимать, вводить и как то с ним еще взаимодействовать) до тех пор, пока дополнительное не будет закрыто. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Вместо `show` используйте `showAndWait`.

Comment: @zed, не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо указать [модальность](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html) [APPLICATION_MODAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#APPLICATION_MODAL) и использовать метод [showAndWait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--):

```
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
stage.showAndWait();
```

Если надо заблокировать только какое-то родительское окно, то это окно надо указать в качестве владельца и использовать [WINDOW_MODAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#WINDOW_MODAL)

```
stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.showAndWait();
```